# I working on this C++ code and can't get it to work...see below

Tags: c++, loops

Can't get this to work...roadblock....help?!?  I am new to this and am trying to write game code for a C++ course at Delco CC.  Any help would be appreciated greatly.  When it runs it will not loop as intented and thus I'm stuck from moving forward in coding the rest of my game.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int findMap()
{
int space;
cout<<"|  1  |  2  |  3  |"<<endl;
cout<<"|_____|_____|_____|"<<endl;
cout<<"|  4  |  5  |  6  |"<<endl;
cout<<"|_____|_____|_____|"<<endl;
cout<<"|  7  |  8  |  9  |"<<endl;
cout<<"|     |     |     |"<<endl;

cout<<"What space is your map in?"<<endl;
cin>> space;
if (space == 4||8)
{
          cout<<"Nope! There's nothing in here."<<endl;
          return findMap;
          }
if (space == 5||6)
{
          cout<<"Tough luck, you only found blank map paper. It's
useless."<<endl
          return findMap;
          }
if (space == 1||7)
{
          cout<<"You found poision gas. You failed."<<endl;
          return 0;
          }
if (space == 1)
{
          cout<<"Yippie! You found your map!"<<endl;
          }
if (space == 9)
{
          cout<<"Well, you found your wallet..."<<endl;
          return findMap;
          }


}

int game(findMap)
{
string name;
int findMap;
cout<<"It appears that you have been lost at sea."<<endl;
cout<<"But don't worry, you'll only have to survive until you reach
land, for this round."<<endl;
cout<<"Anyways, why don't you tell me your name?"<<endl;
cin>> name;
cout<<"Well, "<< name<<", do yourself a favour and find your
map..."<<endl;
cout<<findMap<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I dont see a loop anywhere in your code.  Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: now i see you're trying to call findMap - you're not calling it correctly.  Does this compile with a lot of warnings?  Read them if so.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `if (space == 4||8)` Where does this keep coming from?!

Comment: What the heck are you doing with `findMap`? First it's declared as a function, then passed into `game` as an argument without a type. Then shadowed with a local `int` variable`.

Comment: May I suggest starting from scratch? You clearly need to learn the basic principles of C++, programming conventions, etc. It's like you're playing with a knife without even knowing how a blade works.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't we have an appropriate canonical duplicate for this question? Just curious ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Probably but I cba to find it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, same for me. Looks like questions like this are too often being closed as being a _"simple/typographical error"_. Tough job to setup a _canonical question_ for this kind of misconception, I'd appreciate to have one though.

Answer (score 2):

Such the classic defect <s>typo</s>.

The logical *OR* is specified as:

```
if ((space == 1) || (space ==7))
```

This has to do with <s>the order of evaluations</s> semantics.

**Edit 1: Why your version isn't working correctly**
In the expression:

```
 (space == 1 || 7)
```

The phrase `1||7` is evaluated first to a true condition.
The expression now is:

```
  (space == true)
```

The identifier `true` has type `bool`, so it is converted to the same type as `space`, which is `int`.  The `int` representation of `true` is `1`.
Substituting gives us:

```
(space == 1)
```

You were kind of lucky with this one, but the case for `7` doesn't exist.  All of your `if` statements are evaluated the same way.

Comment: It has more to do with semantics than order of evaluations.

Comment: And its not a typo either, = vs == would be a typo.

Comment: Incorporated suggested comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception in c++. The or (`||`) operator is usually used in boolean values. Thus when you check `(space == 1||7)` it first evaluates `space == 1` which would evaluate to true if and only if space is equal to 1. Then after it evaluates `(space == 1)` it applies the or operator on 7. Since 7 always evaluates to true `(space == 1||7)` always evaluates to true because the or operator evaluates to true if any part in the expression evaluates to true.

What you want is `(space == 1 || space == 7)` because it will evaluate the first, then the second sub expression (i.e. `space == 1`, then `space == 7`) and return true if and only if either of them evaluated to true.